# Blank page in browser when I run ipython notebook --pylab inline

Tags: macos, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Mac OS Mountain Lion. I recently installed the ipython. I want to use ipython notebook, so I also installed the dependent packages for ipython notebook. But when I run the command

```
ipython notebook --pylib inline
```

My safari browser is opened. But the web page is blank and no In[] symbol. I cannot type in command.

I also tried to use Chrome. The result was the same.
Any help is predicated! Thanks in advance.

I'm using Python 2.7. All my browsers are updated.

Comment: There are also these warnings appearing in my terminal:

WARNING:root:404 GET /static/components/requirejs/require.js (127.0.0.1) 0.74ms
WARNING:root:404 GET /static/components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css (127.0.0.1) 0.59ms
WARNING:root:404 GET /static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js (127.0.0.1) 0.73ms
WARNING:root:404 GET /static/components/jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js (127.0.0.1) 0.65ms
WARNING:root:404 GET /static/components/bootstrap/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js (127.0.0.1) 0.59ms

Comment: Where did you install IPython from? There's a known issue with Github tarballs (they don't include submodules). You can install [from PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipython), or if you want to use the bleeding edge, clone the Github repo and run `python setup.py install` from there.

Comment: @Negelis, did you ever get a resolution for this. I have just brought up ipython-1.1.0 under python-2.7.3 on Linux (CentOS 5.8), and have exactly the same symptoms, including the GET failures. It occurs with multiple browsers. The page source looks sensible, but the actual page display is completely blank.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem on both safari and firefox on Mac, and resolved it by clearing the browser's caches ...

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't seem to help.

I have a related question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318650/ipython-notebook-launch-and-display-issues?rq=1